# SQL Server Setup RAID 5, RAID 10

Tags: sql-server, sql

I am new to setting up SQL Servers and Vms. My predecessor used Raid 5 for C Drive where the SQL installation resided and RAID 10 for both database files and database logs.

I was wondering whether that is correct or should RAID 5 be utilized for SQL database files instead?

Any help?

Answer (score 3):

Try hard not to use RAID 5 for ANYTHING, especially with large 7.2krpm disks as they're statistically likely to introduce unrecoverable data errors during any disk replacement/rebuilding activities. RAID 10 is by far and away the best option from a performance and data integrity perspective, in fact I'd go as far as saying that using R5 is considered unprofessional by seasoned pros these days.

Comment: The only exceptions I might make for RAID5 in today's world are specific SAN implementations that minimize the risks with RAID5. 3PAR arrays come to mind in the way they use chunklets and custom silicon which leads to incredibly fast rebuild times with very minimal performance impact.